# Stateful Bidirectional LSTM batch size problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement a stateful Bidirectional LSTM but I continue to get the following error:

" Cannot feed value of shape (72, 24, 8) for Tensor 'bidirectional_18_input:0', which has shape '(96, 24, 8) "

This is my code:

```
mdl = Sequential()
# create and fit the LSTM network
mdl.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(12 ,return_sequences=True, stateful=True),batch_input_shape=(96, lags, n_features )))
mdl.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(7,stateful=True)))
mdl.add(Dense(12))
mdl.add(Dense(12))
mdl.add(Dense(1))


mdl.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# early stopping implementation
filepath="weights.best.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=200, mode='min') 
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, early_stop]


# fit network
print(mdl.summary())

for i in range(100):
    mdl.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=96, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2, shuffle=False,
                   callbacks=callbacks_list)
    mdl.reset_states()
```

I have the following architecture:
[image]

I can't understand what is the why it says that I am feeding a value of shape (72,24,8) even if I am using a batch size of 96

Comment: use batch_input_shape=(lags, n_features ). and how many records do you have ie samples

Comment: I have lot of samples, around 35 000

Comment: Since you are using stateful LSTM ,batch size should perfectly divide the number of samples..Otherwise you might get error.In your case it might be that in the last batch there are only 72 samples and not 96.

Comment: normally stateful bidirectional lstm does not exist. because you need initial hidden states on both sides of the sequences

Comment: Yeah a BLSTM doesnt make much sense